# Are there any solutions where spare disk on workstations can be used as a distributed NAS?

Tags: windows, nas, distributed-computing

With a windows based workstation heavy infrastructure, we have a lot of spare disk space.

I am look about to see if there are any solutions where this space can be used as a sort of distributed NAS.

There is nothing solid I have been able to find for Windows but I was wondering if anyone else had seen anything.

An example would be [OpenAFS](http://www.openafs.org) which doesn't really seem to support Windows ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you say OpenAFS "doesn't really support Windows" when they clearly have Windows binaries out?

You could also look into setting up a Windows Server with a DFS role and add all your workstation's shares so they are accessible from a single place. But that'd be more like making shortcuts to each share rather than consolidating all workstation's shares into one big storage space (which is probably what you're after).

Comment: OpenAFS has support for windows clients but not windows servers as I read it.

Comment: @JTew It's considered [experimental](http://docs.openafs.org/ReleaseNotesWindows/ch03s11.html). If you're not planning on implementing this in a critical production environment, I'd say just go for it!